# Fit div with images in screen height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div that simulates table with images that would look like and some styling,
I managed to use CSS to fit images into container width (container as browser or another div), but I am really having hard time with height, SO is it possible to make pictures fit width and height that way?

```css
.cabinet {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.module {
  display: table-cell;
}

.module button {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.module img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabinet">
  <div class="rack">
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rack">
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="module">
      <button>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg" />
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this(height) is actually fitting in the screen size .what is the issue then?

Comment: Well I not quite, if I run snippet i need to use scroll bar to scroll down, i want it to fit without scroll bar (whole thing that is)

Comment: oh if that is the case , go with grid. Flex is mostly used for controlling items having one direction (1 row/column) . Grid will be suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code a bit. Removed unnecessary HTML and CSS . See if this is the result you want.

```css
.cabinet {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="cabinet">
      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="module">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f0/8b/33/f08b339a1cfe789e5e5d725fee58f53d--futuristic-architecture-amazing-architecture.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Wojciech Szabowicz: Is this the behaviour you want. Do let me know :)

Comment: its to fit into the screen size or in this case , a container with 100vh

Comment: Is my code OK for Desktop screen, then Media queries can be used for smaller screens. I didn't actually understood question 100%, I guess :)

Comment: at first even i was a bit confused. But from what i underrstood , he wants to fit those 8 images into a screen size. with a bootstrap class it can be done easily. idk how to do it using flex